# R: re-writing a loop using the "doparallel", "foreach" and "purrr" libraries

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dplyr, parallel-processing

I wrote the following code in R which performs (loop) a series of data manipulation operations on some artificially generated data (the final output is called "final_results"):

```
#load library
    library(dplyr)

library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)


####
results_table <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10 ) {
    
    #generate random numbers
    random_1 =  runif(1, 80, 120)
    random_2 =  runif(1, random_1, 120)
    random_3 =  runif(1, 85, 120)
    random_4 =  runif(1, random_3, 120)
    
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    
    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
    
    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))
    
    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))
    
    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1
    
    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2
    
    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3
    
    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4
    
    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1
    
    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2
    
    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3
    
    final_table_2$iteration_number = i
    
    
    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)
    
    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
    
}
```

The above loop works perfectly fine - but I am trying to learn more about R and trying to re-write this loop using other functions from other libraries such as the `"doParallel", "foreach"` and `"purrr"` libraries.

**Option 1:**

I came across the following code in R which shows the general template for writing loops using the "purrr" library (apparently "map_df" is a function that uses the code from the loop):

```
#option 1
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tictoc)


data_gen <- function(){ #here you insert your data generating process
  tibble(
    x = runif(100),
    y = runif(100)
  )
}

N <- 10000 #number of datasets do be generated


tic('method A')  #not necessary, measures the time of the code between 'tic' and 'toc'
output <- tibble(
  i = 1:N
) %>%
  split(.$i) %>%
  map_df(
    ~data_gen()
  )
toc()
```

However, I am not sure how this code can be adapted to fit my example. I first created the `map_df` function:

```
#create map_df function:

map_df <- function() {
    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))

    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)

    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

    split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)

    #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin

    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))

    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))

    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))




    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)

    #group all tables

    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)

    #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                   group_by(cat) %>%
                                   summarize(
                                       mean = mean(diff)
                                   ))

    #add "total mean" to this table
    final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))

    #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
    final_table_2$random_1 = random_1

    final_table_2$random_2 = random_2

    final_table_2$random_3 = random_3

    final_table_2$random_4 = random_4

    final_table_2$split_1 = split_1

    final_table_2$split_2 = split_2

    final_table_2$split_3 = split_3

    final_table_2$iteration_number = i


    results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)

    final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
}
```

But when I try to run the general template, it produces the following error:

```
data_gen <- function(){ #here you insert your data generating process
    tibble(
        # create some data for this example
        a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
        b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
        c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
        train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
    )
}

N <- 10000 #number of datasets do be generated


tic('method A')  #not necessary, measures the time of the code between 'tic' and 'toc'
output <- tibble(
    i = 1:N
) %>%
    split(.$i) %>%
    map_df(
        ~data_gen()
    )
toc() 

Error in map_df(., ~data_gen()) : unused arguments (., ~data_gen())
```

Does anyone know why this error is being produced?

**Option 2** :

I am not sure how the "doParallel" and "foreach" libraries can be used in my example. It seems that all examples with "doParallel" require the user to begin by defining the number of "cores" they wish the computer will use:

```
 library(doParallel)
 cl <- makeCluster(2)
 registerDoParallel(cl)
```

And in the end, the user has to instruct the computer to stop the process:

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

Beyond this, I am not sure how the "doParalell" and the "foreach" library can be used to benefit my example.

Can someone please show me this?
Thanks

Comment: there are some issues in your `data_gen` function itself and `map_df` is a function in `purrr`.  So you may have to create a new name.  The data_gen shows `tibble`, but there is no `,` in between, then it is converted to data.frame.  I am guessing these are typos

Comment: Once you fix that, use either `replicate` or `purrr::rerun` i.e. `N %>% rerun(data_gen())`

Comment: To return a single data, use `bind_rows` at the end `N %>% rerun(data_gen()) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'grp')`

Comment: You may check my update

Answer (score 2):

There are some potential typos in `data_gen` function.

- The `tibble` was created with columns not separated without a `,`

```
 tibble(
        # create some data for this example
        a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10) ####
        b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)####
      ...
```

- It may be better to name other than the already existing functions - `map_df` from `purrr`

---

If we want to execute the function multiple times, use either `replicate` from `base R` or `purrr::rerun`

-function

```
data_gen <- function(){ #here you insert your data generating process
      tibble::tibble(
         # create some data for this example
         a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10),
         b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5),
         c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE))
     
 }
```

-packages used

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(doSNOW)
library(parallel)
```

-sequential run

```
N <- 10 
out <-  N %>% 
   rerun(data_gen()) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

-parallel run

```
no_of_cores = detectCores()
 cl <- makeSOCKcluster(no_of_cores)
 registerDoSNOW(cl)


 out2 <- foreach(i = seq_len(N), .combine='rbind', 
         .packages = "tibble",        
           .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
       data_gen()
   }
 stopCluster(cl)
```

-checking the number of rows

```
nrow(out)
#[1] 10000
nrow(out2)
#[1] 10000
```

---

The above function was just to show how to run the simple function `data_gen` sequentially and in `parallel`.  With the OP's full function, we can call the `data_gen()` inside the outer function (`map_new_fn`) and that function is called in parallel or sequentially

```
map_new_fn <- function() {


    results_table <- data.frame()
     train_data <- data_gen()     
     train_data <- train_data %>%
         mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))

     train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
     

     #new splits
     a_table = train_data %>%
         filter(cat == "a") %>%
         select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

     b_table = train_data %>%
         filter(cat == "b") %>%
         select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

     c_table = train_data %>%
         filter(cat == "c") %>%
         select(a1, b1, c1, cat)

     split_1 =  runif(1,0, 1)
     split_2 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
     split_3 =  runif(1, 0, 1)

     #calculate 60th quantile ("quant") for each bin

     table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                              mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))

     table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                              mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))

     table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                              mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))




     #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
     table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
     table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
     table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)

     #group all tables

     final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)

     #create a table: for each bin, calculate the average of "diff"
     final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table %>%
                                    group_by(cat) %>%
                                    summarize(
                                        mean = mean(diff)
                                    ))

     #add "total mean" to this table
     final_table_2 = data.frame(final_table_2 %>% add_row(cat = "total", mean = mean(final_table$diff)))

     #format this table: add the random criteria to this table for reference
     final_table_2$random_1 = random_1

     final_table_2$random_2 = random_2

     final_table_2$random_3 = random_3

     final_table_2$random_4 = random_4

     final_table_2$split_1 = split_1

     final_table_2$split_2 = split_2

     final_table_2$split_3 = split_3

     final_table_2$iteration_number = i


     results_table <- rbind(results_table, final_table_2)

     final_results = dcast(setDT(results_table), iteration_number + random_1 + random_2 + random_3 + random_4 + split_1 + split_2 + split_3 ~ cat, value.var = 'mean')
     final_results
 }
```

-run sequentially

```
out1_new <- N %>%
       rerun(map_new_fn()) %>%
       bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

-run parallely

```
no_of_cores = detectCores()
 cl <- makeSOCKcluster(no_of_cores)
 registerDoSNOW(cl)


 out2_new <- foreach(i = seq_len(N), .combine='rbind', 
         .export = c("data_gen", "map_new_fn"),
         .packages = c("tibble", "dplyr", "data.table"),        
           .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
       map_new_fn()
   }
 stopCluster(cl)
```

-check the output number of rows

```
nrow(out1_new)
[1] 10
nrow(out2_new)
[1] 10
```

Comment: thank you for your wonderful answer! I am having some errors when I try to run "out2_new": error calling combine function:
<simpleError in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol): Item 43 has 11 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 12 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.>
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol): Item 64 has 11 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 12 columns. To fill missing columns use fill=TRUE.>
error calling combine function:

Comment: Do you know why this is happening? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @stats555 I did tested the code and didn't find this error though